How to flatten commit history into one branch?
While experimenting with git, a meaningless knot emerged that I would like to unravel now.
​* 422383b
​* 202fd84
​|\  
​* | e619d7c
​| * d730427
​|/|   
​* | 030baa6
​| * 4a0498d
​| * 00e04c9
​* | 83bdd92
​| * c8f17a6
​| * 4214f5c
​|/  
​* 156f2a3
​* 0a5d68a

Instead, it could be something like this:
​* 422383b
​* 202fd84
​* e619d7c
​* d730427
​* 030baa6
​* 4a0498d
​* 00e04c9
​* 83bdd92
​* c8f17a6
​* 4214f5c
​* 156f2a3
​* 0a5d68a


Does this answer your question? Flattening Simple Git History Commits

run git rebase --onto 156f2a3 156f2a3 422383b. By default, it should not rebase merges so you should end up with a linear history.

@eftshift0 Caution, though! This does not achieve the desired order. You need git rebase -i and manual arrangment of the commits.

Does this answer your question? Linearize git history, preserving all commits
